# Print vs select output order in Visual Studio (was: Temporary SQL table changes on it's own???)

Tags: visual-studio, t-sql, temp-tables

Please tell me I'm dreaming or something.

I'm doing oldschool tsql tree traversal without CTE. Here's my vanilla stack table.

```
CREATE TABLE #stack (DepartmentId int, level int)
```

Later in the loop code I've ran into a problem, so I've sprinkled the code with Print statements and SELECT * FROM #stack. Here's the relevant part for this question

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #stack WHERE level = @level)
        BEGIN
            PRINT 'First in the loop:'
            SELECT * FROM #stack WHERE level = @level
            PRINT 'Same query 1:'
            SELECT * FROM #stack WHERE level = @level
```

This renders this output:

```
First in the loop:
DepartmentId                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     level                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
No rows affected.
(1 row(s) returned)
Same query 1:
DepartmentId                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     level                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
No rows affected.
(1 row(s) returned)
```

**My question is obviously, how can the content of the first column change between the two select statements?**

**UPDATE:**
The above output is from running the query from a database project in Visual Studio 2008.
However, running the query from SQL Server Management Studio produces the following result:

```
First in the loop:
DepartmentId level
------------ -----------
NULL         1

Same query 1:
DepartmentId level
------------ -----------
NULL         1
```

My code is not far from the classic msdn article "Expanding Hierarchies", but I'm using it to fill a cache table with id's instead of building strings.

I'm also running it in a transaction like this:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
SET XACT_ABORT ON
BEGIN TRANSACTION
```

**EDIT 2:**
It seems the loop is contributing to the confusion, but the main culprit is the order of the Print statements and the Select statements in Visual Studio.

Here's the minimized code that produces the relevant output:

```
PRINT 'First in the loop:'
SELECT 'The order '
PRINT 'Same query 1:'
SELECT 'is quite puzzling'
PRINT 'Same query 2:'
SELECT 'isn´t it?'
```

Here's what VS 2008 outputs:

```
Executing selected script from a_error_repro.sql

First in the loop:
Same query 1:
Column1    
---------- 
The order  
No rows affected.
(1 row(s) returned)
Same query 2:
Column1      
------------ 
is quite puzzling. 
No rows affected.
(1 row(s) returned)
Column1   
--------- 
isn´t it? 
No rows affected.
(1 row(s) returned)
Finished executing selected script from a_error_repro.sql
```

It seems regarding the content of the temporary tables, we're actually fine, but the output order of print statements in VS 2008 is a bit disturbing.

I've added a bug report as recommended by Martin. Thank you. :)
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/664137/wrong-output-order-of-print-vs-select-when-executing-sql-statements-in-visual-studio

Comment: What is the difference between DepartmentId (from your output) and ParentId (from #stack table)?

Comment: Thank you for noticing. That was a mistake I made when I translated the code for posting here. It is really the same. I've changed it above now.

Comment: Where are you running this? Where does the `No rows affected.` message come from? And is thie Microsoft SQL Server or Sybase?

Comment: I think we need to see more code.  You are inserting or updating records in #stack.

Comment: I'm running it from Visual Studio 2008, by selecting a part of the stored procedure, right clicking and choosing Run Selection.

Comment: @Blazes Yes, elsewhere in the loop I do that, but the code pieces looks exactly like above. There's no other rows between those select and print statements.

Comment: @Martin It's SQL Server 2008 Express R2

Comment: Indeed doesn't seem possible can you produce a complete script that reproduces the issue?

Comment: @Martin I've added more info above. I'm in the process of creating a sample script.

Comment: @Blazes @Martin sample script done, a bit shorter than I first thought...

Comment: @Carl R: We are being drip-fed information here.  Can you post the whole script please.  It is very important to see how you are populating/modifying #stack.  e.g., you might be selecting DepartmentId, getting NULL, and updating the row where level=1...

Comment: @Carl - I see the same behaviour as you in VS 2010 with the `PRINT` statements displayed before the output of a `SELECT` that was executed first. Might be worth searching [the `Connect` site](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback) to see if this is a known issue and if not submitting it.

Comment: @Blazes All you need is the last script after "Edit 2". :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was not in the code nor in the tables. It was a problem with the output order of the print statements vs select statements in visual studio.

See: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/664137/wrong-output-order-of-print-vs-select-when-executing-sql-statements-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 0):

It might be that the data within your second select is out of scope (Change the single #-sign to 2 #-signs and see if you get the same result.). Since that seems strange with the code you showed, please add some more code.

Comment: It is in the same scope. Sorry. I'm in the process of removing cruft from the sample code now.